Hyundai i10 2017 pulls to the right even after the alignment
Good afternoon, people!
Last December I got some problems with the audio control buttons on my steering wheel, so I got them changed, and during that the steering wheel was taken off and put on again.
After that I did an alignment because the car started pulling slightly to the left, and that fixed it. However, on my way back from the workshop I got into accident (talk about bad luck!) - a guy cut me off, couldn't brake in time and hit him with my front left part of the bumper at around 25-30 km/h, resulting in bent left front fender and some scratches on the bumper.
After that, I've noticed that the car started pulling to the right - and I've done another alignment.
Still, even after that it feels like the car is pulling to the right, sometimes better, sometimes worse.
Here are the alignments results from before and after the accident.
Now, I'm no car engineer, but I've noticed that some secondary angles are wildly different, and I'm not sure what to make of it - is my axle bent? Or suspension is messed up? Or maybe the steering wheel was put on wrong?
I've tried with the workshops, but the insurance one told me everything is in order (of course!), and another one also couldn't find anything.
If any of the labels are unclear, let me know - they are translated from German and may not use the correct terms, even though I tried my best.


